# WordPress Admin Area - How To Disable Editing the Publish Date?

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to have other people publish post on my WordPress website, but I do not want them to be able to edit the post date in the admin area (or anywhere else). Is there any way to disable this feature? Ideally, WordPress should get the current time from the server and insert it into the database for the initial post (no user input accepted), and not be modifiable from that point.

Removing the edit link in CSS is not what I am looking for, I need to disable this functionality at its core.

I thought of using the wp_insert_post_data filter, but I quickly discovered that this could be bypassed with quick edit, and there just seemed to be too many gotchas that I may not have thought of.

```
function insert_post_data_handler( $data , $postarr ) {

    if ( $data['post_status'] === 'auto-draft' ){
        // Do Nothing, WordPress Does not generate date from POST/GET request
    } elseif ( $data['post_status'] !== 'publish' ){
        // Must be a draft, so automatically make the post date the current date/time
        $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $data['post_date'] = $datetime;
        $data['post_date_gmt'] = $datetime;
        $data['post_modified'] = $datetime;
        $data['post_modified_gmt'] = $datetime;
    } elseif ( $data['post_status'] === 'publish' ){
        // Could either be an update to a post, or a brand new post
        if ( isset( $postarr['original_post_status'] ) ){
            if( $postarr['original_post_status'] !== 'publish' && $data['post_status'] === 'publish' ){
                // This is a brand new post
                $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $data['post_date'] = $datetime;
                $data['post_date_gmt'] = $datetime;                
            } else {
                // This must be an update, do not change the date
                global $post;
                $org_datetime = $post->post_date;
                $current_datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $data['post_date'] = $org_datetime;
                $data['post_date_gmt'] = $org_datetime;
                $data['post_modified'] = $current_datetime;
                $data['post_modified_gmt'] = $current_datetime;
            }
        } elseif( $postarr['original_post_status'] === 'publish' && $data['post_status'] !== 'publish' ){
                // Sorry, not allowing anyone to revert to draft/pending once published
                die('The status can not be reverted once posted');
        }          
    } else {
        die('Uncaught exception');
    }

    return $data;
}

add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'insert_post_data_handler', '99', 2 );
```

Comment: Your question is ? Does the codes above have any problem?

Comment: If you want to use plugin then I would suggest you [User Submitted Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-submitted-posts/) plugin.

Comment: The snippet of code does not disable to feature. I thought that filtering the data would be sufficient, but doing a quick-edit would bypass this filter. So my point is that I would have to think of every possible way a post date could be altered and compensate for that. Isnt there a way to just turn this feature off?